# Setting up Simulator for Automated UITesting

Tags: ios, automated-tests, simulator, xcode-ui-testing, run-script

I need to setup my **Simulators** for Automated UITesting.
Especially removing Autocorrection, Spellchecking, Prediction etc from the Keyboard.

I am doing that for *one* Simulator like that:

```
plutil -replace KeyboardAutocapitalization -bool NO -- ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/319FF855-F54C-4BB7-BDED-F0CC4B1FF8FC/data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preferences.plist
```

The problem with that is, when the Tests run on *another* Device, it won't setup the simulator since the UUID is hardcoded.

I also am able to a booted / selected Simulator like this:

```
currentUUID="$(xcrun simctl list devices | grep "iPhone 7 (" | egrep -o -i "[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}")"
```

where I have to put in `iPhone 7 (` in order to get the `UUID`of only the iPhone 7 and not the 7+. This also only works if I really selected the iPhone 7 as a Simulator in Xcode before.
Another way of doing it is to replace the `iPhone 7 (` with `booted`.

But in order for this to work, the script needs the Simulator to already run. And when it does already run, changing the plist files won't actually update the settings on the Simulator.

How would I be able to launch a Simulator and then grab it's UUID before setting it up?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

[plu](https://github.com/plu) has created a [`simctl`](https://github.com/plu/simctl) gem which is able to manipulate simulators. It can create, delete, boot device and do much more. One interesting feature is disabling keyboard helpers.
If you are using [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) you can create new private lane which will disable keyboard helpers for all.

To install this gem use:

```bash
[sudo] gem install simctl
```

In the `Fastfile` add this lane:

```ruby
private_lane :disable_keyboard_helpers do
  require "simctl"
  SimCtl.list_devices.each do |d| 
    d.settings.disable_keyboard_helpers
  end
end
```

Now in your test lane, you can use `disable_keyboard_helpers` like this one:

```ruby
lane :test do |options|
  disable_keyboard_helpers
  scan
end
```

If you are not using Fastlane you can still use `simctl` by executing Ruby command directly:

```bash
ruby -e "require 'simctl'; SimCtl.list_devices.each { |d| d.settings.disable_keyboard_helpers }"
```